# Recover python process after ssh broken pipe

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm running a python process on an EC2 instance which takes a few hours to complete. During that time I lost my ssh connection because my internet went out and the pipe broke. I've relogged into my machine but can no longer see the output of my process. I believe the process is still running. Is there a way to recover the output of the process so I can keep track of its progress?

Comment: I don't know what you can do this time, but next time, try running your remote process inside `screen` or `tmux`. Then you can disconnect and reconnect any time.